# Why does the service destroy on ICS but not previous versions?

Tags: android, service

There is a service which I wrote that manages location issues. It runs on 2.3.3 (Galaxy S2) perfectly but when I run the app on ICS (Galaxy s3) onDestroy method gets called. What can be the possible differences between both of them?

**EDIT 1:** 
**The problem at the below line. Why or how does it force to destroy the service?**

`_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);`

**EDIT 2 (PROBLEMS)**

1. If gps is disabled it does not turn gps on and goes to onDestroy
2. If network provider is the selected provider then goes to onDestroy again.

The point I cant get it how all of these run on 2.3.3 correctly?

```
   private void turnGPSOn(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
```

getBestProvider()

```
private String getBestProvider(){
    //gps açıksa fine'a göre ara, değilse dandik providerı dön.
    return isGpsEnabled()==true ? _locationManager.getBestProvider(getFineCriteria(), false) : _locationManager.getBestProvider(getCoarseCriteria(), false);
}
```

Comment: Maybe some code would help? What about LogCat? Any message there?

Comment: You should see some messages in the logcat to indicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible difference between them is RAM management, as ICS occupy more RAM space Android process manager destroy some services and in your case the service you called is one of them.